# How can I "inverse match" with regex?

Tags: regex, inverse-match

I'm processing a file, line-by-line, and I'd like to do an inverse match.  For instance, I want to match lines where there is a string of six letters, but only if these six letters are not '*Andrea*'. How should I do that?

I'm using [RegexBuddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RegexBuddy), but still having trouble.

Comment: It actually sounds like you might do better to give us a bit more information about what you're doing, and see if someone can offer an alternative solution. Typically, attempting to parse an entire file by constructing a regular expression that matches each line is a rather complicated route :)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
(?!Andrea).{6}
```

Assuming your regexp engine supports negative lookaheads...

...or maybe you'd prefer to use `[A-Za-z]{6}` in place of `.{6}`

Note that lookaheads and lookbehinds are generally not the right way to "inverse" a regular expression match. Regexps aren't really set up for doing negative matching; they leave that to whatever language you are using them with.

Comment: You need to add the ^ that @Vinko Vrsalovic uses so that it won't match on "ndrea\n"

Comment: . doesn't match \n by default (some languages [eg Perl] allow you to switch on that behaviour, but by default . matches everything BUT \n).

Comment: (plus, the OP never mentioned the string had to occur at the start of the line)

Comment: Andrea: OP means "original poster", so, I was referring to you :)

Comment: Dan: ok i did not learn the SO slang yet :P Thank you :) The same thing is commented on the Vinko Vrsalovic answer

Comment: I'm guessing the {6} is set to 6 because that is the length of the string "Andrea", but if this _is_ the case, it should be made clear in the answer.

Comment: This only works for strings that are exactly 6 characters long, as requested. Dmytro shared the answer for any length strings [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1909960/819417).

Answer (score 62):

For Python/Java,

```
^(.(?!(some text)))*$
```

http://www.lisnichenko.com/articles/javapython-inverse-regex.html

Comment: This doesn't work.  You're thinking of the Tempered Greedy Token idiom. but the dot has to go *after* the lookahead, not before.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat).  But that approach is overkill for this task anyway.

Comment: Don't know which language it is written in, but worked like a charm in Sublime text to clean up my test data. Thanks!

Comment: @AlanMoore Actually, it'll _almost_ work for this use case.  However, if `some text` starts the line, it will return the wrong result.

Comment: @Zenexer, that's what I meant.  If the dot is after the lookahead instead of before, it works perfectly.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://superuser.com/a/1334072/411849) that explains more. I do not understand why `?!` and not just `!`.

Comment: See [Tempered Greedy Token - What is different about placing the dot before the negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) to understand why this answer is wrong.

Comment: The link is broken: *"Unable to connect. Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at www.lisnichenko.com."*

Answer (score 46):

In [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) and similar variants, you can actually create a regex that matches any line not containing a value:

```
^(?:(?!Andrea).)*$
```

This is called [a tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/1188377).  The downside is that it doesn't perform well.

Comment: This is the Tempered Greedy Token in long form.  Just put the dot (or `[\s\S]`, which is only useful in JavaScript) after the second lookahead, and you don't need the first one: `^(?:(?!Andrea).)*$`.

Comment: @AlanMoore Nice!  I couldn't find any established pattern that worked like that, so I came up with my own.  Rather than me taking your answer, you should provide that as your own.

Comment: That's okay, there are already plenty of good answers.  And you deserve credit for inventing the idiom on your own.  Cheers!

Comment: Why do you suggest using `[\S\s]`? OP is talking about matching lines, not containing "Andrea" word. Not about checking if the whole string contains this word. Am I missing something?

Comment: @x-yuri I think you're right. I probably answered the question I had was I first visited this page, ignoring the discrepancy. My connection isn't good enough to update the answer right now, though (< 10 kbps)

Comment: Okay, undeleting this and making an attempt at cleaning this up.

Comment: Thank you! This answer was actually handy, because I was struggling with understanding how Black formatter handles the pattern provided to `--exlude`. I was able to set it up to ignore everything except files in few directories.

Comment: Worked in search/replace visual code feature

Answer (score 13):

The capabilities and syntax of the regex implementation matter.

You could use look-ahead. Using Python as an example,

```
import re

not_andrea = re.compile('(?!Andrea)\w{6}', re.IGNORECASE)
```

To break that down:

**(?!Andrea)** means 'match if the next 6 characters are not "Andrea"'; if so then

**\w** means a "word character" - alphanumeric characters.  This is equivalent to the class [a-zA-Z0-9_]

**\w{6}** means exactly six word characters.

**re.IGNORECASE** means that you will exclude "Andrea", "andrea", "ANDREA" ...

Another way is to use your program logic - use all lines not matching *Andrea* and put them through a second regex to check for six characters.  Or first check for at least six word characters, and then check that it does not match *Andrea*.

Answer (score 8):

[Negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?!Andrea)
```

This is not exactly an inverted match, but it's the best you can directly do with regex. Not all platforms support them though.

Comment: Until the questioner clarifies, I don't see that the match has to start at the start of the line.  So why the ^ ?

Comment: Because I understood he wanted to check at the beginning of the line, edited given clarifications

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do this in RegexBuddy, there are two ways to get a list of all lines not matching a regex.

On the toolbar on the Test panel, set the test scope to "Line by line".  When you do that, an item List All Lines without Matches will appear under the List All button on the same toolbar.  (If you don't see the List All button, click the Match button in the main toolbar.)

On the GREP panel, you can turn on the "line-based" and the "invert results" checkboxes to get a list of non-matching lines in the files you're grepping through.

Answer (score 5):

`(?!` is useful in practice. Although strictly speaking, looking ahead is not a regular expression as defined mathematically.

You can write an inverted regular expression manually.

Here is [a program](http://www.vidarholen.net/contents/junk/files/invert.hs) to calculate the result automatically.
Its result is machine generated, which is usually much more complex than hand writing one. But the result works.

Answer (score 5):

I just came up with this method which may be hardware intensive but it is working:

You can replace all characters which match the regex by an empty string.

This is a oneliner:

`notMatched = re.sub(regex, "", string)`

I used this because I was forced to use a very complex regex and couldn't figure out how to invert every part of it within a reasonable amount of time.

**This will only return you the string result, not any match objects!**

Comment: What language? Python?

Answer (score 4):

If you have the possibility to do two regex matches for the inverse and join them together you can use two capturing groups to first capture everything before your regex

`^((?!yourRegex).)*`

and then capture everything behind your regex

`(?<=yourRegex).*`

This works for most regexes. One problem I discovered was when I had a quantifier like {2,4} at the end. Then you gotta get creative.

Answer (score -4):

In Perl you can do:

```
process($line) if ($line =~ !/Andrea/);
```

Comment: That syntax is wrong. I think you mean process($line) if $line !~ /Andrea/