# How to filter App Engine access logs for requests without a parameter

Tags: regex, google-app-engine

I want to introduce a new mandatory parameter to the API of my webservice I have deployed on App Engine. However, before I enable the server side check I want to check whether all the clients have been updated to send the parameter.

App Engine provides a GUI for searching the access log. I want to use this to find all logs which don't contain the new parameter.

I know from [How to "inverse match" with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164414/how-to-inverse-match-with-regex) that I should be able to use the regex "(?!paramname)" but this currently returns an error from App Engine:

```
Client Error

The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.
```

Is there another way for me to do this? I'm not interested in solutions which involve me downloading the logs.

EDIT: This has already been raised as a bug: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1874

Comment: If querying the logs online doesn't work, you could download them and do it offline using `appcfg.py download_logs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you asked *not* for methods involving downloading logs, but since you could list all your logs and grep away the ones you don't want in your shell with just a single line using appcfg.py I still thought it would be worth noting.

So if you wanted to dump all your logs by browsers that are **not** Safari you could run:

```
$ appcfg.py request_logs --include_all --severity=0 /path/to/app - | grep -v "Safari"
```

Comment: Somehow I thought downloading the logs would be more complex. I will try this tomorrow.