# Regex to select all .c files except ones with a certain prefix

Tags: regex, makefile

I have what should be a real simple regex question. I'm making a makefile and need one target to compile all the source in my directory except one or two files that have a named prefix of ttem_endian_port. What regex can I use to make this as simple as possible?

I was thinking something like [^ttem_endian_port*]*.c but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do you really need a regex? `make`'s built-in functions can do this as well.

```
ALL_SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
SRCS     := $(filter-out ttem_endian_port%.c, $(ALL_SRCS))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^[^(ttem_endian_port)]*.c
```

- The first ^ means 'beginning of string'.
- Then, you need to parenthesize ttem_endian_port to make the regexp engine understand that you want to negate the whole term with your ^

Answer (score 2):

Regexp were not made to do a *negative* search. If you really want to use regexp, you can make a **lookahead** (not all the engines support it):

```
^(?!ttem_endian_port).*\.c$
```

Also, don't forget to **escape** the dot.
Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/164414/710951) for more information.