# RegEx to tell if a string is not a specific string

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Suppose I want to match all strings except one: "ABC"
How can I do this?

I need this for a [regular expression model validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx) in asp.net mvc 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would do like

```
(?!ABC)
```

So for example:

```
^(?!ABC$).*
```

All the strings that aren't `ABC`

Decomposed it means:

```
^ beginning of the string
(?!ABC$) not ABC followed by end-of-string
.* all the characters of the string (not necessary to terminate it with $ because it is an eager quantifier)
```

Technically you could do something like

```
^.*(?<!^ABC)$
```

Decomposed it means

```
^ beginning of the string
.* all the characters of the string 
(?<!^ABC) last three characters captured aren't beginning-of-the-string and ABC 
$ end of the string (necessary otherwise the Regex could capture `AB` of `ABC` and be successfull)
```

using a negative look behind, but it is more complex to read (and to write)

Ah and clearly not all the regex implementations implement them :-) .NET one does.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer this definitively without knowing what language you are using, since there are many flavors of regular expressions, but you can do this with negative lookahead.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/164419/1112402

Comment: I need this for a regular expression model validation in asp.net mvc 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!.*ABC)^.*$
```

This will exclude all strings which contains ABC.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help:

```
^(?!^ABC$).*$
```

With this expression you're going to get all possible strings `(.*)` between beginning `(^)` and the end `($)` but those that are exactly `^ABC$.`