# regexp inverse mac-address match

Tags: regex, perl

I wrote this perl regex in order to get all mac-addresses:

```
^(?([0-9A-Fa-f]{12}))$
```

This works fine, but the [inverse match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164414/how-to-inverse-match-with-regex) (all string without mac-address) doesn't works:

```
^(?!([0-9A-Fa-f]{12}))$
```

what is the best way to write this regex?

Comment: Should anyone have forgotten, a MAC address is usually something like `A1-B2-32-DD-5F-FF`, or in the OPs case, probably `A2B232DD5FFF`.

Comment: Find all the matches and replace  emtpry string (`""`)

Comment: you're right, but in my case the mac-address does not have special characters

Comment: Provide some sample input that you're trying to match or not match.

Comment: related: [Regular expression to match string not containing a word?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/406230/4279)

Comment: @anubhava: I want to match this string: "23af23af23ca", but i do not want match this string: "realm\username"

Comment: Have you tried: `(?!^([0-9A-Fa-f]{12}$))^.*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your original pattern you are starting a conditional (the `(?(...)` part), but without then/else clause. I am quite sure you didn't want this.

Your second pattern has the problem, that you are checking a condition with your [negated lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but you don't match something. So change it to

```
^(?![0-9A-Fa-f]{12}$).*$
```

This will match any pattern that is not `[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}`.