# How to write regex that match the answer block?

Tags: regex

I want to match the answer blocks (the bold ones).

A) **I ve II** B) **III ve IV** C) **III ve IV** D) **III ve IV**   E) **III ve IV**

So far i wrote this.

```
(?:[A|B|C|D|E]\) )
```

It match this

**A)** I ve II **B)** III ve IV **C)** III ve IV **D)** III ve IV   **E)** III ve IV

But when i append (.*) to it it matches

A) **I ve II B) III ve IV C) III ve IV D) III ve IV E) III ve IV**

How i can reverse match the regex that i wrote?

I need to reverse match the text because it can be everything on this block. A) example B) hello C) world D) goodbye E) something else

Thank you,

http://regexr.com/3a8fq

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "inverse match" with regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164414/how-to-inverse-match-with-regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using a lookahead based regex.

```
(?s)[A-E]\)\s*((?:(?!\s*[A-E]\)).)+)
```

Comment: But the string must have to be single line, otherwise it does not work. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
(?<=[A-E]\) ).*?(?= [A-E]\)|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do

```
/I(II)? ve I(I|V)/
```

If your language supports inverse lookaheads:

```
?!(?:[A|B|C|D|E]\) )
```

Comment: So long as the answers always take that format, sure, but I'm guessing that they might not, and the idea is to key off the labels.

Comment: Thank you, but i forgot to mention it can be everyting on this block. A) example B) hello C) world D) goodbye E) something else