# Excluding files in Path::Tiny using negative lookahead regex

Tags: regex, perl

Using [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny). It has a method: [children](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#children) which could be used as:

```
@paths = path("/tmp")->children( qr/\.txt$/ );
```

> If an optional qr// argument is provided, it only returns objects for
>   child names that match the given regular expression. Only the base
>   name is used for matching

So the

```
@paths = path("/tmp")->children( qr/\A(foo|bar|baz)\z/ );
```

will return either `foo` `bar` `baz` files found in the `/tmp`.

I need the opposite, want any file but NOT the `(foo|bar|baz)` ones.

The following could filter out the unwanted ones,

```
@paths = grep { $_->basename !~ /^(foo|bar|baz)$/ } path("/tmp")->children;
```

but wondering how to write the `qr` for it.

**So, the question**: How to create the `qr` expression for: any file but **not** `foo|bar|baz`?

I tried the negative lookahead

```
path(...)->children( qr/\A (?!(foo|bar|baz)) \z/x );
```

but, it doesn't do what I think it should do  :) - e.g. my regex is wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/164414/1331451 woruld work, but it's weird. You are almost right with your negative lookahead, but you need to match something after the lookahead, like three of anything: `(?!(foo|bar|baz))...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `\z` *inside* the negative look-ahead

```
qr/\A(?!(?:foo|bar|baz)\z)/
```