# JQuery Validation Engine : invert regex match

Tags: regex, validation

I am using JQuery Validation Engine, and I'd like to prevent any phone number in a text field.

I have this expression, which matches any French phone numer :

```
((\+|00)33\s?|0)[1-9](\-?\.?\s?\d{2}){4}
```

It matches the numbers like that:

0102030405, 01.02.03.04.05, 01-02-03-04-05, +33102030405, 0033102030405, etc...

But I need to invert this matchs, and this does not work :

```
!(((\+|00)33\s?|0)[1-9](\-?\.?\s?\d{2}){4})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invert the regular expression using a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead):

```
^((?!((\+|00)33\s?|0)[1-9](\-?\.?\s?\d{2}){4}).)*$
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38846455

Comment: Great ! Thank you ausi