# How to “inverse match” with regex without content?

Tags: regex

I have read [How to "inverse match" with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164414/how-to-inverse-match-with-regex) and i would like to know if i can apply it to a non-content regex. In particular i'm talking about: `^[A-z0-9+\/]{44}$`

I tried https://regex101.com/r/NmOs7Z/1 but it does not work

Comment: Question is not clear to me. can you add example input and desired output please

Comment: `[A-z]` will match all characters from A to Z and will include some special characters in between A-Z and a-z  like `]` `[` etc and finally will match a-z also, as the range in character set works by taking everything between the ascii values of the two start and end character. Do you really want this or want to correct your regex?

Comment: You also need to *match* some characters between the `^` and the `$` eg `.{44}$`, for a start

Comment: Imagine the regex above but only matching when the regex above wouldnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get exactly what you really, but from my understanding you want to match the two lines in your demo 
So what i did :

```
^(?![a-zA-Z0-9+\/]{44}).*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NmOs7Z/3)

Comment: No i want the regex to NoT match the two lines

Comment: Here u go i did some modification.