# invert reqular expression for excluding folders/files (used for Electron Packager)

Tags: regex, electron

I'm getting mad, can't get it to work and can't find a solution.
So how can I inverse the following regular expression?
All tested strings should match - except those including "dist" or "node_modules". It need this regex for [Electron Packager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager#usage) build command to ignore all folders/files excepts those having the string in path name.

regular expression to be inversed: `(?=dist|node_modules)\S+`

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word, maybe `^(?!.*(dist|node_modules)).*` or `^(?!.*(dist|node_modules))` is all you need.

Comment: This question may contain the solution you require: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164414/how-to-inverse-match-with-regex

Comment: I checked a lot of questions before - in a regex checker the example by Wiktor Stribiżew works but in this case I have to provide it as a command line parameter in bash and it doesn't work. aaaargh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

conclusion: it was not possible to find a working RegEx which will do the job in combination with Electron packager. I used a custom packaging script instead where it's possible to use NodeJS an delete folders or whatever your app needs.