# Invert intruder grep match in burp

Tags: regex, burp

I want the intruder to flag the attack response only when a specific string **DOESN'T MATCH**

The string is: `Invalid credentials`

Tried using RegExp inverse match: https://stackoverflow.com/a/164419/10362396

[image]

It is not working

[image]

Please note, the current selected response is when the username and password are correct.

Comment: As per your linked answer *Note that lookaheads and lookbehinds are generally not the right way to "inverse" a regular expression match. Regexps aren't really set up for doing negative matching, they leave that to whatever language you are using them with.*

Comment: That said, you might make it work but you'll need to use some anchoring on where the string is not expected to be found. Can you post a screenshot of a response containing the "Invalid credentials"?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I am using Burpsuite for the bWAPP application. Here is the response string I want to match. https://github.com/raesene/bWAPP/blob/master/app/login.php#L123