# Regex - to match number NOT in a sequence of character classes

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Sample file contents:

```
create 664 root utmp
```

I would like to match any number that is NOT this:

```
[0-6][0-4][0]
```

So it would match `664` and `641`, but not `440` and `640`.

My full regex is this:

```
^([\s]`*`?)create[\s]+?([0]?[0-6][0-6][0-6])[\s]+?(\w+?)[\s]+?(\w+?)[\s]`*`?$
```

But I would like to basically say:

- match on not this:

  ```
  ([0]?[0-6][0-6][0-6])
  ```

Comment: Depending on the tool or language, you can use a negative lookahead `create(?!\s+[0-6][0-4]0)\s+(\d{3})\b` https://regex101.com/r/jalFbw/1

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977251/regular-expressions-and-negating-a-whole-character-group

Comment: thanks "bird" and Nasser - helpful comments. 
Also helpful: https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Looking_Ahead_and_Behind.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at: [How can I "inverse match" with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164414/how-can-i-inverse-match-with-regex)

and found: `(?![0-6][0-4][0])[0-9]{3}` see: https://regex101.com/r/D3JRfu/1

As far as I can see this works.

Answer (score 0):

Using the regex in your sample `[0]?[0-6][0-6][0-6]`,
it can be done with a couple of negative assertions.
There has to be boundary assertions to force a constraint on the number of
digits as well as values.

```
(?<!\d)(?![0]?[0-6][0-6][0-6](?!\d))\d+
```

The first negative look behind can be replaced with a `\s` when its put in the larger regex.

```
 (?<! \d )
 (?!
    
    [0]? [0-6] [0-6] [0-6] 
    (?! \d )
    
 )
 \d+
```